# wordpress blog post order change

Tags: php, wordpress

I have purchased a template from ThemeForest named as envision. but i want to make a little change in it that template have blog layouts and i want to add sort function in php file to show the latest posts, here is the file in which i am trying to add sorting option but it doesn't work for me

```
$i = 0; 

if ( empty($image_width) ) {
    if ( $columns == 1 )
        $image_width = 960;
    else 
        $image_width = 480;
}

if ( $image_ratio && $image_width ) {
    $image_height = cloudfw_match_ratio( $image_width, $image_ratio );  
}

$atts[ 'show_side_date_year' ] = false;


while( $posts->have_posts() ) : 
    $posts->the_post();
    $post_data = $this->get_post();

    /** Item number */
    $i++;
    $item_content = '';
    $item_classes = array();
    $item_classes[] = 'ui--blog-item ui--animation ui--accent-gradient-hover-parent clearfix';

    $item_classes[] = 'layout--' . $raw_layout;

    if ( $i == $post_count )
        $item_classes[] = 'last-item'; 

    $item_content .= "<div".
        cloudfw_make_class( $item_classes, true ) .
        ">";

        $link_element = array();
        $link_element[0]  = "<a class=\"ui--blog-link\" href=\"". $post_data['permalink'] ."\"";
        $link_element[0] .= ">";
        $link_element[1]  = "</a>";

        $item_content .= $this->side( $post_data, $atts );

        $item_content .= "<div class=\"ui--blog-content-wrapper\">";

            $item_content .= "<div class=\"ui--blog-header\">";
                $item_content .= "<{$title_element} class=\"ui--blog-title entry-title\">" . $link_element[0] . $post_data['title'] . $link_element[1] . "</{$title_element}>"; 

                $metas = $this->get_blog_metas( $metas_primary, $post_data );
                $likes = $this->get_blog_metas( $metas_secondary, $post_data );

            $item_content .= "</div>";

            $excerpt = $this->get_excerpt( array('readmore' => $readmore, 'excerpt' => $show_excerpt, 'excerpt_length' => $excerpt_length, 'use_more_link' => false ) );
            if ( !empty($excerpt)) {
                $item_content .= "<div class=\"ui--blog-content\">";
                    $item_content .= $excerpt;
                $item_content .= "</div>";
            }

            $item_content .= "<div class=\"ui--blog-readmore more-link\">";
                $item_content .= "<a class=\"btn btn-small ". cloudfw_make_button_style( cloudfw_get_option( 'blog_template_mini',  'button_color', 'btn-secondary muted' ), true ) . "\" href=\"". $post_data['permalink'] ."\"";
                $item_content .= ">";
                    $item_content .= $readmore;
                $item_content .= "</a>";
            $item_content .= "</div>";

        $item_content .= "</div>";

    $item_content .= "</div>";

    if ( $columns > 1 ) {
        $column_array = array();
        $column_array['class'] = array();
        $column_array['_key'] = 'blog_mini';

        //$content_out .= $item_content;
        $content_out .= cloudfw_UI_column( $column_array, $item_content, '1of' . $columns . ( $i % $columns == 0 ? '_last' : '' ), $i == $post_count );
    } else {
        $content_out .= $item_content;
    }

endwhile;
```

Comment: So whats the question, you've said what you are trying to do but not asked anything?

Comment: This seems like the kind of question that is perhaps best asked to the theme designer / on their support forums.

Comment: i tried to contact them but no answer from their support or theme designer

Answer (score 0):

Go for

```
$posts = query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=title&order=desc' );
while($posts->have_posts()) :
```

insetad of

```
while( $posts->have_posts() ) :
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wp_get_recent_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) function to get recent posts

```
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 10,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>
```